# Obtaining themed attributes from built in Android styles

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

Given a Context that has been themed with `AppTheme` (shown below), is it possible to programmatically obtain the color **#ff11cc00** without referencing `R.style.MyButtonStyle`, `R.style.AppTheme`, or `android.R.style.Theme_Light`?

The objective is to obtain the button text color that was set by the theme without being bound to a particular theme or app-declared resource. Using `android.R.style.Widget_Button` and `android.R.attr.textColor` is okay.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff11cc00</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say without referencing `MyButtonStyle` or `AppTheme`

Comment: I'll update the question to clarify that.

Comment: if you have just defined color in colors.xml like this: `<color name="mycolor">#ff11cc00</color>` you can reference it like: `context.getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor);`, in which case you don't need to reference `AppTheme` or `MyButtonStyle`

Comment: I added more detail to the question, and mentioned that the idea is to avoid being tied to any app-declared resource, including <color>s or <style>s. Using only the built in Android styles and attributes.

Comment: Color and style are all theme dependent. So when you say you want to obtain the text color used by buttons it has to depend on theme.

Comment: With the Context you can obtain the theme using context.getTheme(). There are also various context.obtainStyledAttributes() methods that can be used. I can't figure out how to access an attribute belonging to a built in Android style such as @android:style/Widget.Button using these methods.

Comment: Have posted an answer for what i could think of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.buttonStyle, outValue , true);
    int[] attributes = new int[1];
    attributes[0] = android.R.attr.textColor;
    TypedArray styledAttributes = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(outValue.resourceId, attributes);
    int color = styledAttributes.getColor(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of this round about way, may be someone else will know better:

```
int theme ;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
  theme = android.R.style.Theme;
} else {
  theme = android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault;
}
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, theme);
Button button = new Button(wrapper);
ColorStateList colorStateList = button.getTextColors();
colorStateList.getColorForState(button.getDrawableState(), R.color.default_color);
```

Comment: I can confirm that this approach does work, though you only need the last 3 lines if you already have a Context. Applying the theme to a Button is the only way I've been able to make this happen so far. I believe the Button can access android.internal.R.styles which may not be accessible from applications. Ideally though, I'd like to know that there isn't a cleaner way to do this before accepting this answer.

Comment: If you don't apply default theme to button and have overwritten button theme somewhere inside your style, you will not get the default color used by the button. Hence you need the default theme and ContextThemeWrapper.

Comment: That's true, as-is this answer would get the color from the default theme. In my question I tried to mention that my Context has been themed with AppTheme and I want to obtain the resulting color that has been set to android.R.style.buttonStyle's android:textColor attribute. Using a real button works in both cases. I'm just hoping there's a way to do this without allocating a throwaway View.

Comment: However if you use `ApplicationContext` for creating the `Button`, that should also work. Then you would not have to go and create the `ContextThemeWrapper`. Because again the Theme is not applied to `ApplicationContext`

Comment: Just saw your previous comment, understood what you mean. I hope there is a better way to get it.